# Is it possible, with a linux host, to clone incoming (SNMP) UDP packets to another UDP port of the same host?

Tags: networking, udp, clone, iptables, packets

I have a linux RedHat host that receives UDP SNMP traps on port 162.
I would like to clone incoming UDP packets to another port of the same host and the same network interface (for example UDP port 1772).

Please keep in mind that I want to preserve everything of the original packets (source IP first).

Is there a way to achieve the goal using maybe iptables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/236503/need-to-duplicate-udp-packets-to-multiple-destinations-via-iptables

Comment: ... and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618827/snmpv3-to-snmpv2-glue-layer

Answer (score 0):

That could be done with iptables on v1.4.21(my version).
Just use TEE to another port such as 8081